# Google Webmaster Tools: Why do I have so many links from my top domain to my subdomain?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, subdomain

I have a subdomain under my top domain as follows:

`2index.net`
`quran.2index.net`

In Google Webmaster Tools, for the subdomain `quran.2index.net`, I find that the number of links recorded from the top domain to the subdomain is very large - more than 26k links! While what I really have is just one link to the subdomain from the index page of the top domain.

The following screenshot displays this:

[image]

I'd like to know two things:

1. Why is there so many links from the top domain to the subdomain?
2. Does this negatively affect SEO and my subdomain's indexing in Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "Random Text" tool on your top domain potentially generates an infinite number of pages (unique URLs). Each of these pages links to the jQuery script on the sub domain:

```
<script src="http://quran.2index.net/themed/slate/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

I think this might be the source of the large number of spuriously reported "links".

Comment: But the image shows that the source of the link is 2index.net and it linked to quran.2index.net i.e it is linked to homepage!

Comment: The "Top 1 link" would seem to have its source at 2index.net, but yes, you are right, the links would seem to point to the root of the sub domain - so the script tag might be off track.